# How a single BGP-process establishes sessions with neighbours in different VRFs?

Tags: tcp, bgp, vrf, vrf-lite

In VRF-lite solution scenario, when BGP session is established between CE connected to a VRF in PE. The BGP process or in other words TCP server, is listening on port 179(default) for incoming BGP control packets in the default(global) VRF. So, how does the TCP session is established for a BGP neighbour inside a VRF address family?

CE----TCP session ---------(VRF-A)PE

So, in above topology interface connecting CE is bound to VRF-A, where as the TCP-server(BGP-process) is listening in default/Global VRF.

**So, how does a single BGP-process establishes sessions with neighbours in different VRFs?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurred to me now that, ultimately it is the tcp socket which needs to be bound to a VRF. A single process can create multiple sockets each being bound to different VRF. All that the process(BGP in this case) has to do it to receive the packets arriving on a socket.

I hope my understanding is correct. Please share your comments.